# VBulletin RSS feed to main website

Tags: php, rss, vbulletin

I did not include my website url, it is a vbulletin forum and all rss/xml options are enabled. (that i know of anyways)

```
<?php
// this is the url of the rss feed that you want to display
$feed = curl_init('http://myvbforum.com/external.php?type=rss2&forumid=33');
curl_setopt($feed, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($feed, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
curl_close($feed);
//if the feed exists, then continue...
if ($xml!=''){
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item){
// create variables from the title and description (can also be used for images and  links)
$title = $item->title;
$description = $item->description;
$date = $item->pubDate;
$user = $item->dc:creator;
// displays the title and description on your website, formatted any way you want
echo '<p><b>'.$title.'</b> - On '.$date.' by '.$user.' <br />'.$description.'</p>';
}}
?>
```

This is the code i am using. I didnt have the date on it before but i figured that out by going through my rss2 feed from my forum. However, i cannot figure out how to get who the author of the post is to appear. When i reviewed the rss2 page the only reference to a author i can find is the dc:creator variable. Which i tried adding to my code. However i keep getting a

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in /public_html/bfdm/1/rss.php on line 16

It apparently does not like the :.

I have tried using the DOM load (    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load($feed); ) but neither work.

Basically i just want to pull the subject, date, user and thread content from my Vbulletin posts. Its been driving me crazy for days.

Now all of a sudden im getting

Warning: simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /public_html/bfdm/1/rss.php on line 6

On the code above with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (or at least working when it has a `-`):

```
$user = $item->{'dc:creator'};
```

And the same has to be done with some other special characters in name, like `-`.

*Edit*: not in this case. However, the final, working code should be:

```
<?php
// this is the url of the rss feed that you want to display
$feed = 'URL OF THE RSS'; //replace this with the RSS's URL
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
//if the feed exists, then continue...
if ($xml!=''){
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item){
// create variables from the title and description (can also be used for images and  links)
$title = $item->title;
$description = $item->description;
$date = $item->pubDate;
$user = $item->children('dc', true)->creator;
// displays the title and description on your website, formatted any way you want
echo '<p><b>'.$title.'</b> - On '.$date.' by '.$user.' <br />'.$description.'</p>';
}}
?>
```

Comment: New issue is this

Warning: simplexml_load_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /public_html/bfdm/1/rss.php on line 6

no idea why its suddenly giving that (before i tried using your suggestion)

Comment: Use `$feed = 'http://myvbforum.com/external.php?type=rss2&forumid=33';` and it will work. No need for curl.

Comment: It gives me a few curl errors but im guessing thats the issue from trying to call from a curl that dont exist. However, the posters name still does not appear. Is this an issue with vbulletins RSS2? it is possible with rss instead?

Comment: Remove ALL the curl codes. For the poster name, I'll take a look. Hopefully soon I'll be able to tell why.

Comment: I really appreciate it :). Ive been looking for the last 3 days. I find little snippits here or there but nothing i can seem to pull together. It might just be the RSS2.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. `$user = $item->children('dc', true)->creator;` should work fine.